# Renaming a Unique Key Name MySQL

Tags: mysql

I had a column that had a `UNIQUE KEY` `ExtendedOrderID`.

I renamed this column to `OrderLineItemID`.

Still, when I go to `SHOW CREATE TABLE` it is stating

```
. . . 
UNIQUE KEY `ExtendedOrderID` (`OrderLineItemID`)
. . . ) ENGINE=InnoDB . . .
```

Showing my original column name.

Now, I don't think this is affecting anything, since it's still pointing to the new properly named column `OrderLineItemID`, but how do I completely remove `ExtendedOrderID` from the table and rename it to show properly

```
UNIQUE KEY `OrderLineItemID` (`OrderLineItemID`)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to drop it and then recreate it again with the new name:

```
alter table yourTableName drop index ExtendedOrderID;

create unique index OrderLineItemID on yourTableName (OrderLineItemID);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I am assuming since it's all in the same query that this will have no negative consequences? I was hoping to just rename it instead of dropping it and then re-creating it, perhaps because I'm paranoid.  Is this query virtually the same as a rename?

Comment: There is no problem at all. Unless your database is huge, what would happen is a little delay on that table operations. And yes is "virtually" the same as renaming the index.

Answer (score 6):

You can rename it using the `RENAME INDEX` clause in the `ALTER TABLE` command (since MySQL 5.7).

From the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-index):

> `RENAME INDEX old_index_name TO new_index_name` renames an index. This
>   is a MySQL extension to standard SQL. The content of the table remains
>   unchanged. `old_index_name` must be the name of an existing index in
>   the table that is not dropped by the same `ALTER TABLE` statement.
>   `new_index_name` is the new index name, which cannot duplicate the
>   name of an index in the resulting table after changes have been
>   applied. Neither index name can be `PRIMARY`.

```
ALTER TABLE my_table RENAME INDEX ExtendedOrderID TO OrderLineItemID;
```

Comment: Would be nice to just rename it instead of having to drop and and re-create it (Although I don't think it matters . . . ?)  Anyways, this does not work for me  `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INDEX ExtendedOrderID TO OrderLineItemID' at line 1` I'm on MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Find Indexes list from phpmyadmin and drop your unique index.

[image]